# How to fix "-no-user-package-conf is deprecated" warnings

Tags: haskell, ghc, cabal

Ever since I upgraded to GHC 7.6.2, I'm seeing warnings such as the following:

```
amy@wombat$ cabal install
Resolving dependencies...
Configuring realta-0.1.0.0...
Building realta-0.1.0.0...
Preprocessing executable 'realta-init' for realta-0.1.0.0...

on the commandline: Warning:
    -no-user-package-conf is deprecated: Use -no-user-package-db instead

on the commandline: Warning:
    -package-conf is deprecated: Use -package-db instead
```

The warning probably has something do with http://hackage.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/5977.
I'd like to fix these warnings, if possible, so that I can compile my code with -Werror. Using the command `cabal install -v`, I found out that cabal is using this flag with the ghc command, as shown below.

```
/usr/local/ghc-7.6.2/bin/ghc --make -o dist/build/realta-init/realta-init -hide-all-packages -fbuilding-cabal-package -no-user-package-conf -package-conf  AND SO ON
```

Is there something I can do to get cabal to use the new flags instead? (Note: In my ~/.cabal/config file, I set `user-install: False`, which may be relevant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems to be [fixed](https://github.com/haskell/cabal/issues/1002) in `HEAD` (at least `-package-conf`). You can upgrade `cabal-install` by installing it from the repo or wait for the next release.